# Shared server farm: Possible to connect SharePoint 2010 local farm to Amazon EC2 SQL Server?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql-server, amazon-ec2

We are running **SharePoint 2010** server farm locally. Now it is our requirement to **move SQL Server 2012 on [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_IN&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=ec2_b&sc_content=ec2_e&sc_detail=amazon.ec2&sc_category=ec2&sc_segment=78875081221&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=IN&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!78875081221!e!!g!!amazon.ec2&ef_id=VvjJQAAAAWkkfvsj:20160609063635:s)**.

**Requirement**: We want to connect SharePoint 2010 server on-premise with Amazon EC2 SQL server 2012 (Cloud).

I've googled a lot but can not find the hybrid connection between them. I found many blogs in which they are showing to move SharePoint server along with SQL in the cloud but couldn't able to find for hybrid connection.

My question are:

- Is it **possible to do hybrid connection** between SharePoint and SQL as mentioned above?
- How to connect SharePoint 2010 local server 2012 with Amazon EC2 SQL
  server?

Comment: I don't think it's doable, and it is certainly not recommended even if doable.  The best practice is to keep your database farm as close to your SharePoint servers as possible to minimize lag and round trip times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is very helpful but could you please provide some msdn links or blogs on that so that I can pass it to my client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible but it is not supported( if not meet the requirement). Your topology falls under the stretched farm which has very high requirement.

There is a highly consistent intra-farm latency of <1ms (one way), 99.9% of the time over a period of ten minutes. (Intra-farm latency is commonly defined as the latency between the front-end web servers and the database servers.)
The bandwidth speed must be at least 1 gigabit per second.
[Read more here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748824.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CfgStretchedFarm)

[Also check this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/berryst/2011/04/05/setting-up-sharepoint-2010-stretched-farm/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Information is very useful to me.:)